# Adding values in Python

Tags: python

```
def print2DArray(array):
    for i in array:
        a = (i[2])
        print a

print2DArray([["Y", "X", 5.3], ["B", "A", 10.5], ["E", "F", 25.8]])
```

How do you add the values in the for-loop, for total values like (5.3+10.5+25.8)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print the sum of those numbers (i.e. 41.6), you might want to keep a running total inside your `for` loop, like so:

```
def print2DArray(array):
    total = 0
    for i in array:
        a = (i[2])
        total += a
    print total
```

It might be easier to read, however, if you used the built-in `sum()` function and a generator expression:

```
def print2DArray(array):
    print sum(i[2] for i in array)
```

Comment: Note: For self-documenting code, unpacking in the loop is usually nicer, even if you don't necessarily use the values. e.g. assuming the first two values are the letters indicating a point in a 2D space, it might be `for x, y, val in array:`, `total += val`, or for `sum` approach `sum(val for x, y, val in array)`. Tweak the names to describe your actual scenario of course. It's usually faster to implicitly unpack instead of repeatedly indexing explicitly, and it makes it more obvious what's going on. (Not a criticism of the answer, just adding for OP's benefit).